# VBA Reproduce Error if Err.Number is not expected error number

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to reproduce error raised during runtime (if Err.Number doesn't represent the error I want to handle) Like:

```
On Error Resume Next
Err.Raise UNWANTED_ERROR

If Err.Number = ERROR_I_WANT_TO_HANDLE Then
    'Do my error handling
Else
    'reproduce same error
End If
```

but I'm unable to reproduce the same error because re-raising error will just `continue next` statement and as soon as I enter `On Error Goto 0` in following statements the Err.Number changes from the original error number to 0 and if I put `Err.Raise Err.Number` next to this statement then error changes from 0 to 5 and gets raised but the original produced error is lost

Well to generalize my problem is if a runtime error is not user defined error it should not be suppressed and shall raise as it would have if no error handling was in place

I have tried to google it but all the answers found only address the expected errors and suppress other errors

Comment: Do not use `on error resume next`? Store `Err.Number` in a variable and then revert to `on error goto 0`?

Comment: Oh Great! I was worried about HelpFile and HelpContext arguments but I guess VBA System Errors get these arguments automatically, I tried your solution only providing error number to Err.Raise and I was able to go to correct help file from Error Message Dialog, it works for VBA System Errors, Thanks!